# Lazy Loading using loadChildren error : Too much recursion

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I'm still trying to figure out how modules and component work in Angular.

The problem that I'm having now is that when I'm defining a Module and trying to use it for lazy loading in my routes I'm having an error : too much recursion.

Here is the routing module :

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes= [
  { path : '' ,
    component : MainComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module')
      .then(m => m.MainModule)
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(AppRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule{
}
```

**main.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class MainModule { }
```

P.S : When I'm including the MainModule in the DashboardModule and when I remove the loadChildren function from routing, the error goes away and everything works, but I'd like to know why this is not working when I'm using loadChildren in this module, and why the too much recursion error exactly.

I've gone around the web and I found out that this issue is produced when the routing path is empty , when I change the path to anything else for example : `path : "main"` the lazy loading works and everything comes back to normal.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Acording to lazy modules documentantion, to lazy load Angular modules, use loadChildren **(instead of component)** in your AppRoutingModule routes configuration as follows. You are using both.. Remove the component property of your object.

```
{ path : '' ,
  loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module')
  .then(m => m.MainModule)
},
```

[Lazy loading documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the error (I mean I tried your answer so that I can be sure X) ), and specifying the component along with lazy loading strategy is not wrong. I don't think you understood, the problem is with the empty string path "", if I change it to something else it works, I guess it's an issue in angular, if not there must be an explanation to this.

Comment: If you use loadChildren in Dashboard, the main module must have its own route like this { path : '' ,    component : MainComponent }. Did you configure the routes of main module when implementing the lazy loading version?

Comment: Yes I did Alan, the problem was in the empty path, I guess it's an issue with angular, because when I changed it to "main" it worked fine, so the problem is with the empty path only : ""